# Networkx - update subgraph attributes in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, networkx

I have a set of subgraphs, each containing a subset of a larger graph, `G`.

Each node in these subgraphs has a list of values. I'm hoping to update the `graph.graph` attribute of each subgraph to the mean value of its list of values.

```
for each_subgraph in nx.weakly_connected_components(G):
    subgraph = G.subgraph(list(each_subgraph))
    
     # Calculate mean value for each weakly_connected_component
    mean_value = np.mean(list(nx.get_node_attributes(subgraph,'value').values()))
    
    # Integrate mean value to networkx object
    subgraph.graph['mean_value'] = mean_value
       
 
    # ***Printing this value behaves as expected within for loop***
    print(subgraph.graph['mean_value'])

> > 1, 2, 5, 6, etc
```

However, when I try to reference the `mean_value` after the for loop, all I get is nan:

```
print(subgraph.graph['mean_value'])
> Nan
```

Why is this?

I have tried this (within for loop):

```
    subgraph.graph.update({'mean_value': mean_value})
```

and behavior still exists.

Also, I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58554440/networkx-refuses-to-update-graph-attributes-in-for-loop), among others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `G.subgraph` you are creating a view on the graph `G`. This means that assigning value via `subgraph.graph["mean_value"] = mean_value` will propagate to the original graph `G`. Since this is done via a loop, the value in `G.graph["mean_value"]` will be overwritten during each iteration. The fact that you are observing `nan` value suggests that there is a `nan` value in the `value` attribute of at least one of the nodes in `G`.

Here's a MRE to check:

```py
from numpy import mean, nan

from networkx import (
    DiGraph,
    get_node_attributes,
    set_node_attributes,
    weakly_connected_components,
)

G = DiGraph([(0, 1), (1, 2), (4, 5), (5, 6)])

# set node attributes
values = {k: k for k in range(7)}
set_node_attributes(G, values, "value")
print(G.nodes(data=True))
# [(0, {'value': 0}), (1, {'value': 1}), (2, {'value': 2}), (4, {'value': 4}), (5, {'value': 5}), (6, {'value': 6})]

for each_subgraph in weakly_connected_components(G):
    subgraph = G.subgraph(each_subgraph)
    mean_value = mean(list(get_node_attributes(subgraph, "value").values()))
    subgraph.graph["mean_value"] = mean_value
    print(subgraph.nodes, mean_value)
    # [0, 1, 2] 1.0
    # [4, 5, 6] 5.0

print(G.graph)
# note that the last assigned value is displayed
# {'mean_value': 5.0}
```

If you want to assign a different value to each subgraph, then one option is to store that as a node attribute:

```py
for each_subgraph in weakly_connected_components(G):
    subgraph = G.subgraph(each_subgraph)
    mean_value = mean(list(get_node_attributes(subgraph, "value").values()))
    set_node_attributes(subgraph, mean_value, "mean_value")

print(G.nodes(data=True))
# [(0, {'value': 0, 'mean_value': 1.0}), (1, {'value': 1, 'mean_value': 1.0}), (2, {'value': 2, 'mean_value': 1.0}), (4, {'value': 4, 'mean_value': 5.0}), (5, {'value': 5, 'mean_value': 5.0}), (6, {'value': 6, 'mean_value': 5.0})]
```